# Enzyme: wrapper.find('SickButton').simulate('click') not clicking

Tags: unit-testing, enzyme

enzyme: "^3.6.0"
enzyme-adapter-react-16: "^1.5.0"

So I have a button defined as follows, which isn't clicking:

```html
<SickButton type="button" disabled={loading} onClick={() => { 
addToCart().catch(err => alert(err.message));
}}>
  Add{loading && 'ing'} to Cart
</SickButton>
```

and I'm attempting to test it with the following test expression:

> wrapper.find('SickButton').simulate('click')

How do I do this?

My full test code is as follows:

```html
  it('adds an item to cart when clicked and quantity >=1', async () => {
    let apolloClient;
    let quantity = 1;

    const wrapper = mount(
      <MockedProvider mocks={mocks}>
        <ApolloConsumer>
          {client => {
            apolloClient = client;
            return <AddToCartOrder id="abc123" quantity={quantity}/>;
          }}
        </ApolloConsumer>
      </MockedProvider>
    );
    await wait();
    wrapper.update();
    const { data: { me } } = await apolloClient.query({ query: CURRENT_USER_QUERY });
    // check the cart has no items in it
    console.log(me);
    expect(me.cart).toHaveLength(0);

    // add an item to the cart
    wrapper.find('SickButton').simulate('click');
    await wait();
    // check if the item is in the cart
    const { data: { me: me2 } } = await apolloClient.query({ query: CURRENT_USER_QUERY });
    console.log('me2 = ', me2);
    expect(me2.cart[0].id).toBe('omg123');
    expect(me2.cart[0].quantity).toBe(3);
    expect(me2.cart).toHaveLength(1);
  });
```

Comment: can you post your test code as well?

Comment: @eramit2010 I have amended my original question to include the test code.

Comment: @eramit2010 Any thoughts on this?

Comment: It seems you are testing too much code for unit test. anyway can you try doing wrapper.update() after simulating click.
If i was to write unit test for AddToCartOrder component i just pass mock function as prop and on click that function should be called. i wouldn't worry about updating data and everything. Those things should be tested with Unit testing of your cosumer component.